# Software with PHP annotations?

Tags: php

I'm looking for a program what has a PHP annotations plugin, as well as Doctrine and Symfony plugins. Preferably I would want it to be free and HAS to have a PHP annotation plugin, the others are just a plus. I have heard about sublime text but I don't know if it has what I want. If anyone knows any programs that they can recommend that would be great, thanks!

Comment: Can I ask what it is you want to annotate?  Are you speaking in terms of documenting the code?

Comment: I have been coding PHP fro 20 yeras now, and don't know what a "PHP annotation plugin" is :-( If you can explain more clearly, I am sure that we can hepl you.

Comment: Are you asking for an IDE with tooltips? maybe giving a description of parameters & return values of functions?

Comment: You logged in two weeks ago. Didn't you see these requests for clarification? we really ***do*** want to help you, but you have to help us to help you

Comment: It's fine now..

Comment: What sort of cryptic answer is that? We are here to help people; if you could explain your question and explain what "fine" is, then you might help others in future.

Comment: And, if you have an answer, then please post it, in order to help other people